# Is there a way to integrate spring-data-solr with Tika?

Tags: solr, solrj, apache-tika, solr-cell, spring-data-solr

Is there a way, via configuration, to use spring-data-solr with Tika? Otherwise, is there some alternative to solrj’s `ContentStreamUpdateRequest+addfile` for spring-data-solr?

Currently I am using Solrj + Tika in this manner:

```
SolrServer server = new HttpSolrServer(URL);
...
Tika tika = new Tika();
...
String fileType = tika.detect(path.toFile());
up = new ContentStreamUpdateRequest("/update/extract"); 
up.addFile(path.toFile(), fileType);
up.setParam("literal.id", idField);
...
up.setAction(AbstractUpdateRequest.ACTION.COMMIT, true, true);
NamedList<Object> request = server.request(up);
```

I arrived at this method by successfully following this [ExtractingRequestHandler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler#SolrJ) guide.

Using solr 4.3.0, is is possible get the same result via `spring-data-solr`, instead of having to invoke Solrj directly?

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct support for `ContentStreamUpdateRequest`. The fallback would be to do it  within a `SolrCallback` executed by `SolrTemplate`.

```
NamedList<Object> result = solrTemplate.execute(new SolrCallback<NamedList<Object>>() {

  @Override
  public NamedList<Object> doInSolr(SolrServer solrServer) throws SolrServerException, IOException {
    Tika tika = new Tika();
    // ...
    String fileType = tika.detect(path.toFile());
    ContentStreamUpdateRequest up = new ContentStreamUpdateRequest("/update/extract");
    up.addFile(path.toFile(), fileType);
    up.setParam("literal.id", idField);
    // ...
    up.setAction(org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.AbstractUpdateRequest.ACTION.COMMIT, true, true);
    NamedList<Object> request = solrServer.request(up);
  }

});
```

In case you need this kind of behavior in more repositories then probably this post about [adding custom methods to all repositories](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/solr/spring-data-solr-tutorial-adding-custom-methods-to-all-repositories/) might help.

Comment: Thanks @Chistoph, but I need to avoid use ContentStreamUpdateRequest (solrj)